# How to calculate proportion in R Programming

Tags: r

[This is my data set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4aB0c.png)

Question is how do I calculate the proportion of males over the height of 150 are in the dataset?

Comment: Please post data sets as text instead of screenshots. So others who want to offer an answer do not have to enter the data manually. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `subset` to filter data based on a condition and then compute ratio of lengths of the two dataframes (original and filtered).

```
weight <- c(76,69,64,62,62,57,55,62,60,55)
height <- c(167,167,168,168,168,168,168,168,149,140)
data.foo <- cbind(weight, height) # Example dataset with only height and weight columns

over.150 <- subset(data.foo, height > 150) # filtered data
proportion <- nrow(over.150)/nrow(data.foo)
```

> proportion
>
> [1] 0.8

Comment: thanks .. The approach is useful and worked for other cases as well